# How to logout OAuth 2.0 when stop the program using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I use .net core 7 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google to use google authentication. It is ok but when I stop the program, it is not auto logout. It saves cookies on the browser. 
If I want logout, I call `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();` in the controller. 
How can I auto call `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();` when I stop the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick
First, I create a static variable `public static int  isNew = 0;` 
Then, I put that code to Index action in HomeController

```
if (TimeLife.isNew == 0)
      {
           await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
           TimeLife.isNew = 1;
      }
```

It work good.

 The application will auto logout in the first login